# C++ Switch statement using strings

Tags: c++, string, switch-statement

I am fully aware that switch must be used with int, but my assignment is requiring me to use switch in regards to user input which will be strings.

I've looked and I've seen some mentioning *stoi*, but I'm not sure if that is what my professor is expecting, because we have not been introduced to it yet. I'm completely new to C++, so I'm still learning and this code is not completed yet, but how can I do it?

```
int main()
{
    // Declare Constant variables
    const float DISC_GOLF_RETAIL = 14.96;
    const float ULTIMATE_RETAIL = 20.96;
    const double DISCOUNT1 = 8;
    const float DISCOUNT2 = .16;
    const float DISCOUNT3 = .24;
    const float DISCOUNT4 = .32;
    const double DEC = 100;

    // Declare variables
    double quantity;
    double pricePerDisc;
    double totalSavings;
    double total;
    char userInput;
    float discount;
    string discType;
    string disc1 = "Ultimate Disc";
    string disc2 = "Disc-Golf Disc";


    // Display title
    cout << "Welcome to the Flying-Disc Shop!" << "\n" << endl;

    // Prompt the user for input
    cout << "Enter 'u' for ultimate discs and 'g' for disc golf: ";
    cin >> (userInput);
    cout << endl;

    switch (discType)
    {
        case 1: userInput == 'u' || 'U';
            discType = disc1;
            pricePerDisc = ULTIMATE_RETAIL;
            break;

        case 2: userInput == 'g' || 'G';
            discType = disc2;
            pricePerDisc = DISC_GOLF_RETAIL;
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Invalid disc type." << endl;
            return 0;
    }

    cout << "Enter the number of Ultimate Disc(s): ";
    cin >> (quantity);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "------------Receipt------------" << endl;

    if (quantity > 5 && quantity <= 9)
    {
        discount = DISCOUNT1 / DEC;
        totalSavings = (pricePerDisc * quantity) * discount;
    }
    else if (quantity > 10 && quantity <= 19)
    {
        discount = DISCOUNT2;
        totalSavings = (pricePerDisc * quantity) * discount;
    }
    else if (quantity > 20 && quantity <= 29)
    {
        discount = DISCOUNT3;
        totalSavings = (pricePerDisc * quantity) * discount;
    }
    else if (quantity >= 30)
    {
        discount = DISCOUNT4;
    }

    totalSavings = (pricePerDisc * quantity) * discount;
    total = quantity * pricePerDisc - totalSavings;
    cout << "Disc Type: " << discType << endl;
    cout << "Quantity: " << quantity << endl;
    cout << "Pricer per Disc: " << "$ " << fixed << setprecision(2)
    << pricePerDisc << endl;
    cout << "Total Savings: " << "$ " << "-" << fixed << setprecision(2)
    << totalSavings << endl;
    cout << "Total: " << "$ " << total << fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic:  Use `tolower()` or `toupper()` after receiving a single character.  This will eliminate half of your comparisons.

Comment: Try this:  `switch (discType) { case 'u': /*...*/ case 'g': /*...*/};`

Comment: You may be calculating double the total savings.  You have the calculation inside the `if-else-if` ladder *and* after the ladder.  I recommend removing the `totalSavings` calculation from inside all the `if` statements.

Comment: FWIW a string can be hashed to an integer value and used in a switch statement, but that’s probably beyond your assignment

Comment: This must be a duplicate. What is the canonical question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For single *char* responses, you can use the `switch/case` statement:

```
switch (userInput)
{
    case 'g':
    case 'G': 
       /* ... */
       break;
    case 'u':
    case 'U': 
       // ...
       break;
    default:
       // ...
       break;
}
```

A single character can be treated differently than a string.  A string is usually consists of more than one character.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion in regards to the totalSavings also, didn't even realize

Comment: Addendum: `switch` only works on integer types. `char` is an integer type. You can fake out the behaviour with a `map`/`unordered_map` mapping strings to the function to be run when the string is received.